# Thread-safe extension method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, extension-methods

I have a very simple extension method that looks like this:

```
public static string ToUserPageTimeFormat(this DateTime TheTime)
{
    return TheTime.Month + "." + TheTime.Day + "." + TheTime.Year + "."  + TheTime.Hour + "." + TheTime.Minute;
}
```

I made it in one line. Is this guaranteed to be thread safe?

Comment: `I made it in one line. Is this guaranteed to be thread safe?` What does this mean?

Comment: Being "on one line" does not make anything thread safe. `x++` in a method, by itself, is not thread safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's thread-safe. Essentially, your method will have its own private copy of the  `DateTime` argument since it is passed by *value*  - a copy is first created and then handed to the method. This copy is private to the method and isn't visible to other threads - and therefore can't possibly be mutated by them.

This would *not* be the case if you had used a `ref` parameter:

```
// Not thread-safe.
public static string ToUserPageTimeFormat(ref DateTime TheTime){ ... }
```

In such a hypothetical scenario, the argument *could* be mutated on another thread in the midst of execution of this method. The fact that `DateTime` is an immutable type is irrelevant in this case since it is a struct, and [a struct does not own its own storage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/31/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-two.aspx).

For example, it would then be possible for this method to return an "impossible" formatted date such as "2.31.2012.14.33", resulting from "torn" reads in the midst of multiple write operations.

Comment: Correct answer but DateTime is immutable so the 'private copy' isn't relevant.

Comment: @Henk: Are you talking about the second part of the answer? You don't agree with it?

Comment: @Henk: Basically, if we pass by reference, the fact that it immutable is irrelevant in the face of it being a value type - the storage could still be mutable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `DateTime` is a struct, and therefore is copied to the functional call instead of just passing a reference.  This is due to structs being value types and not reference types.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why this isn't thread-safe, as far as I can tell, each thread will have an object of Datetime on its stack, so there's no shared data here and therefore no need for locking. see the wikipedia page about [thread-safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety)